# Label font size is increasing in simulator in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xib

I have been facing an issue with UILabel font size as shown in Storyboard and simulator snapshots. Font size is larger in the simulator.

Any guess why is this happening.

**Note -** I don't want to Autoshrink label text as it fits in UIlabel frame as shown in XIB. That's why I have used Fixed size font.

[image: Text size in Simulator doesn't fit]

[image: XIB]
[image: Attribute Inspector for UIlabel]